# How many coins do Nipper Plants steal?

Tags: super-mario-rpg-2023

In the Pipe Vault, when you land on a Nipper Plant an animation of Mario losing coins plays. How many coins do the Nipper Plants actually steal?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You lose two coins each time you land on a Nipper Plant. This is shown in the animation. If you only have 1 coin, only one coin will fly out of Mario. If you have 0 coins, the coin loss visual and sound effect won't play.